# Openjdk installation error on Win10 x64 - /usr/bin/dpkg returned error code (1)

Tags: java, windows, ubuntu, javac, amd-processor

Have a problem installing JDK on Windows-10 x64 computer, while attempting to install `openjdk-9`, would repeatedly encounter message: `Errors were encountered while processing`. This was after running `sudo apt-get update` as well as install with `--fix-missing`. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance!

[image: Error Output]

Comment: If you are trying to install openjdk under wsfl(unbuntu shell for windows) you probably want the headless version. The error appears to be that you already have the headless version openjdk-9-jdk-headless installed.

Comment: headless does not have any of the graphical libraries as wsfl doesn't have any display capabilities (AFAIK) ,   Is that what you want or are you just trying to install java for windows ? If you run which java , whats the outpuit

Comment: Oh man, I had no idea..  But, when I run java *file*, it tells me to install java? So not sure whether it's set up incorrectly or not there.. Also, excuse my ignorance, but what's the difference between the headless version and normal?

Comment: Output is The program 'java' can be found in the following packages:
 * default-jre
 * gcj-5-jre-headless
 * openjdk-8-jre-headless
 * gcj-4.8-jre-headless
 * gcj-4.9-jre-headless
 * openjdk-9-jre-headless
Try: sudo apt install <selected package>

Comment: Could it have been that I had installed java for windows but am using an ubuntu shell which is causing this error?

Comment: Have you got a default java and default javac set ? see https://askubuntu.com/questions/315646/update-java-alternatives-vs-update-alternatives-config-java

Comment: Ok, I tried installing jdk9-headless and it seems to have worked. I'm thinking I had an imcomplete installation which trying install the normal jdk9 would conflict with.